# Slight SQL error with COUNT inside moderately complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following query to return some stats and I'm having a slight issue. The query works fine but sometimes offers is incorrect. On the occasions that it is wrong it shows offers as being the same number as item_views. I have no idea why really. Wondered if someone could help me out.

```
SELECT i.id, 
i.title, 
i.slug, 
i.seller_id as seller_id, 
i.date_added as date_added, 
a.slug as area_slug, 
COUNT(o.id) as offer, 
COUNT(v.item_id) as total_item_views, 
(COUNT(v.item_id) / COUNT(o.id)) * 100 conversion, 
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.time_ended) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.time_started)) / 60 difference_minutes,
SUM(CASE WHEN v.time_ended - v.time_started < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) bounce,
COUNT(DISTINCT v.session_id) unique_views

FROM item as i

LEFT JOIN offer as o
ON i.id = o.item_id

LEFT JOIN viewed_item as v
ON i.id = v.item_id

INNER JOIN area as a
ON a.id = i.area_id

WHERE i.id = 1
```

Thanks for your time

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)` any time you're using joins.

More information on DISTINCT can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html).

Comment: Thanks for that! Really helped me out and the reference

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not entirely sure I completely understand how it works, but I know that it works. @Johnny

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the count of the distinct ids?  This will depend on your data and desired results.  If the ids you are attempting to count are distinct, then you can add that to your count statements -- `COUNT(DISTINCT o.id)` for example.

However, if you want to count the overall records in each table and those ids are not distinct, you'll need to use a subquery for each count.